# Internal server error 500 when calling php script

Tags: php, ajax

Im trying to call a php script to send a mail containing information from a contact form. After the form has been validated and i try to call the scrip im getting a 500 internal server error.

This is where i call the script and it works.

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//Check if the validation was passed.
if($("#contact-form .error-message").size() === 0) {

    xmlHttp.open("POST", "scripts/send_mail.php");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.send("name="+name.value+"&email="+email.value+"&message="+message.value+"&g-recaptcha-response="+captcha);
}
```

This is the script that is called

```
<?php
require_once '../init.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

$from = 'noreply@hotmail.com';
$to = 'mymail@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from ' . $name;
$body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

//Verify the captcha by sending a POST-request to Google's server.
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$data = array('secret' => 'xxx', 'response' => $captcha);
$options = array(
'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data),
),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$result = json_decode($result, true);



//If the verification of the captcha was successful.
if($result['success']) {

mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)

echo "Thank you! Your message has been received.";
}
else echo "Failed to submit, please try again.";
```

Does anyone know what could possibly cause this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Enable the php error_reporting and give the exact errors.

Comment: look at the server error log for details about the 500. Oh, and thanks for your google secret key.

Comment: add log messages throughout the code, look at the server logs, replace that post with hardcoded variables and open the page in your browser, or at least say what you have tried and what results you got...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a closing semicolon on the line:

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)
```

It should be

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);
```

Comment: Wow, how did i not see that... Thanks a lot